# How to delete an element from an array using lenses

Tags: purescript, lenses

I'm trying to remove an element from an `Array a` using the index of the element but I can't find a way to do it with `Lens`es. I'm also wondering why `Array` does not provide an instance for the `At` lens. Any pointer on it?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm also wondering why Array does not provide an instance for the `At` lens.

You can look at the `Control.Lens.At` [module docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:at) for a hint:

> ... not Array-like ones, where you cannot satisfy the Lens laws

One of the laws which breaks is `set l v' (set l v s) ≡ set l v' s`. The reason being that deleting an index moves the other indices. So the following can't make sense:

```hs
myArray
  & at 6 .~ Nothing
  & at 6 .~ Just 10
```

I don't know of a way to have deleting array elements be Lens like.

Comment: Alright ! Makes sense for lens laws ! Didn´t got the hint from [Pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-profunctor-lenses/8.0.0/docs/Data.Lens.At)